# Running a program with timeout

Tags: time, gnu-coreutils

I am running the timeout  command of GNU Coreutils,

> gtimeout 600 python myprogram.py

According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html),

> duration is a floating point number followed by an optional unit:
>
> ‘s’ for seconds (the default) ‘m’ for minutes ‘h’ for hours ‘d’ for
>   days

Thus, the '`python myprogram.py` part should terminate within 600 seconds (10 minutes). To my surprise, the command actually timeouts after 1 hour. Why?

Comment: Maybe your python script isn't responding to SIGTERM correctly? Try adding `-s 9`, e.g. `gtimeout -s 9 600 python myprogram.py`, to send SIGKILL instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I will probably accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right solution in your case, you would have to try it. Right now it was a guess and I thought it's not enough for an actual answer. But the thing is that there are two ways to terminate a process: the signal "SIGTERM" which basically asks a process to terminate (it may refuse to do so), and "SIGKILL" which can't be blocked and will force the process to be terminated by the OS. `gtimeout` normally sends SIGTERM (like `kill` does). You can use `-s` to specify a different signal, like `9` (same as `KILL`, the name of the signal), like you would do with `kill -9`.

Comment: See also: http://programmergamer.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/clarification-on-sigint-sigterm-sigkill.html

Comment: @CherryDT I just tried. You are right. It is due to the missing '-s 9' part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! I made an answer out of my comment so you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your program ignores SIGTERM, the signal which is used by `gtimeout` to "kindly ask the program to terminate".

You can have `gtimeout` use SIGKILL instead, which can't be ignored or blocked, by adding the parameter `-s 9` like this:

```
gtimeout -s 9 python myprogram.py
```